# aws open search not able to insert data

Tags: javascript, kibana, amazon-opensearch

i have given all the required permission from the aws. this error occurs when i tried to create an index.
Error response:
ResponseError: security_exception: [security_exception] Reason: no permissions for [indices:admin/create] and User [name=arn:aws:iam::999999999999:user/media-s3, backend_roles=[], requestedTenant=null]
not able to identify cause of this error.
how to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

ok, so i got the solution,

1. you need to login to kibana(click on the dashboard link [OpenSearch Dashboards URL in aws console]).

2.path to open dashboard(Amazon OpenSearch > ServiceDomains > your domain name)

3. in the roles section select all_access.
4. your end path should be link this.Security > Roles > all_access > Map user
5. now in the users input past your arn user.
6. in the error copy after 'User [name=', so you copy this

'arn:aws:iam::999999999999:user/media-s3' past it into the user input and click on map.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Instructions for OpenSearch Dashboards:**

1. Log into AWS and go to Amazon OpenSearch Service > Domains > [Your domain]
2. Click the link for "OpenSearch Dashboards URL"
3. Now inside the OpenSearch Dashboard, go to Menu > OpenSearch Plugins > Security
4. Click "Explore existing roles"
5. Find an adequate role. The easiest is `all_access`. Click that.
6. Click the "Mapped users" tab.
7. Click "Manage mapping"
8. In the Users field, add the full ARN of the IAM role. This is formatted like `arn:aws:iam::############:role/xxxxxxxxxx`
9. Click "Map"